# Posting and Paging Through Results

Tags: php, mysql

I have a pagination code I picked up somewhere online. The code works very well as the query is hard-coded, but am struggling to work out how to post a search query to the page and step through the results.

For example I would like to use a search form with two text fields age and sex; send the query to the script and step through the results one at a time.
Here's the script;

```
<?php 

?>
<!doctype html public "-//w3c//dtd html 3.2//en">

<html>

<head>
<title>paging script in PHP</title>
</head>

<body bgcolor="#ffffff" text="#000000" link="#0000ff" vlink="#800080" alink="#ff0000">
<?php
require "config.php";           // All database details will be included here 

$theBreed = NULL;
$page_name="testpage.php"; //  If you use this code with a different page ( or file ) name then change this 

    // To take care global variable if OFF
$start=$_GET['start'];  
if(!($start > 0)) {                         // This variable is set to zero for the first page
$start = 0;
}

$eu = ($start -0);                
$limit = 1;                                 // No of records to be shown per page.
$this1 = $eu + $limit; 
$back = $eu - $limit; 
$next = $eu + $limit; 


/////////////// WE have to find out the number of records in our table. We will use this to break the pages///////

$query2="SELECT * FROM students";
$result2=mysql_query($query2);
echo mysql_error();
$nume=mysql_num_rows($result2);
/////// The variable nume above will store the total number of records in the table////

/////////// Now let us print the table headers ////////////////
$bgcolor="#f1f1f1";
echo "<TABLE width=50% align=center  cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0> <tr>";
echo "<td  bgcolor='dfdfdf' >&nbsp;<font face='arial,verdana,helvetica' color='#000000' size='4'>ID</font></td>";

echo "<td  bgcolor='dfdfdf' >&nbsp;<font face='arial,verdana,helvetica' color='#000000' size='4'>Name</font></td>";
echo "<td  bgcolor='dfdfdf' >&nbsp;<font face='arial,verdana,helvetica' color='#000000' size='4'>Sex</font></td>";
echo "<td  bgcolor='dfdfdf'>&nbsp;<font face='arial,verdana,helvetica' color='#000000' size='4'>Breed</font></td></tr>";

////////////// Now let us start executing the query with variables $eu and $limit  set at the top of the page///////////
$query=" SELECT * FROM students limit $eu, $limit ";
$result=mysql_query($query);
echo mysql_error();

//////////////// Now we will display the returned records in side the rows of the table/////////
while($noticia = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
if($bgcolor=='#f1f1f1'){$bgcolor='#ffffff';}
else{$bgcolor='#f1f1f1';}

echo "<tr >";
echo "<td align=left bgcolor=$bgcolor id='title'>&nbsp;<font face='Verdana' size='2'>$noticia[id]</font></td>"; 

echo "<td align=left bgcolor=$bgcolor id='title'>&nbsp;<font face='Verdana' size='2'>$noticia[name]</font></td>"; 
echo "<td align=left bgcolor=$bgcolor id='title'>&nbsp;<font face='Verdana' size='2'>$noticia[sex]</font></td>"; 
echo "<td align=left bgcolor=$bgcolor id='title'>&nbsp;<font face='Verdana' size='2'>$noticia[breed]</font></td>"; 

echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
////////////////////////////// End of displaying the table with records ////////////////////////

///// Variables set for advance paging///////////
$p_limit=10; // This should be more than $limit and set to a value for whick links to be breaked

$p_f= 0;    
$p_f=$_GET['p_f'];                              // To take care global variable if OFF
if(!($p_f > 0)) {                         // This variable is set to zero for the first page
$p_f = 0;
}



$p_fwd=$p_f+$p_limit;
$p_back=$p_f-$p_limit;
//////////// End of variables for advance paging ///////////////
/////////////// Start the buttom links with Prev and next link with page numbers /////////////////
echo "<table align = 'center' width='50%'><tr><td  align='left' width='20%'>";
if($p_f<>0){print "<a href='$page_name?start=$p_back&p_f=$p_back'><font face='Verdana' size='2'>PREV $p_limit</font></a>"; }
echo "</td><td  align='left' width='10%'>";
//// if our variable $back is equal to 0 or more then only we will display the link to move back ////////
if($back >=0 and ($back >=$p_f)) { 
print "<a href='$page_name?start=$back&p_f=$p_f'><font face='Verdana' size='2'>PREV</font></a>"; 
} 



echo "</td><td  align='right' width='10%'>";
///////////// If we are not in the last page then Next link will be displayed. Here we check that /////
if($this1 < $nume and $this1 <($p_f+$p_limit)) { 
print "<a href='$page_name?start=$next&p_f=$p_f'><font face='Verdana' size='2'>NEXT</font></a>";} 
echo "</td><td  align='right' width='20%'>";
if($p_fwd < $nume){
print "<a href='$page_name?start=$p_fwd&p_f=$p_fwd'><font face='Verdana' size='2'>NEXT $p_limit</font></a>"; 
}
echo "</td></tr></table>";


?>

</body>

</html>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For security reasons you don't want to post a query to that page, it's better to put the query in the code on that page and then send some information with your post to invoke the search.

So let's start with the queries.  If you want to query based on age and sex you could use something like:

```
$query2 = "SELECT * FROM students WHERE Age >= $min_age AND Age <= $max_age AND Sex = '$sex'";
$query = "SELECT * FROM students WHERE Age >= $min_age AND Age <= $max_age AND Sex = '$sex' LIMIT $eu, $limit";
```

Now you'll need to update the PHP script to handle 4 new parameters:

1. $min_age
2. $max_age
3. $sex
4. $action

The fourth parameter (action) will be used to specify that we want to perform a search as opposed to using the existing query which returns all results.

Now to update the code.  Note you only have to add a little extra to take care of this:

First handle your POST variables and apply some checking for valid values to prevent a SQL-injection attack:

```
$min_age = $_POST['min_age'];
$max_age = $_POST['max_age'];
$sex = $_POST['sex'];
if(!is_numeric($min_age) || $min_age < 0 || !is_numeric($max_age) || $max_age < 0 || ($sex != 'm' && $sex != 'f'))
    throw new Exception("Invalid parameters passed");
```

Next, wrap the $query2 query in a conditional statement so we can use the modified version for search if we're doing a search:

```
if(isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == 'search')
{
    //Doing a search
    $query2 = "SELECT * FROM students WHERE Age >= $min_age AND Age <= $max_age AND Sex = '$sex'";
}
else
{
    /////////////// WE have to find out the number of records in our table. We will use this to break the pages///////

    $query2="SELECT * FROM students";
}
```

Now make a similar change to the main query further down the page

```
if(isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == 'search')
{
    $query = "SELECT * FROM students WHERE Age >= $min_age AND Age <= $max_age AND Sex = '$sex' LIMIT $eu, $limit";
}
else
    $query=" SELECT * FROM students limit $eu, $limit ";
}
```

That takes care of the PHP end.  Now all that remains is to create your search form and add a hidden field containing the action:

```
<form method="post" action="yourphpfile.php">
    <input type='hidden' name='action' value='search'/>
    Min Age: <input type='text' name='min_age'/>
    Max Age: <input type='text' name='max_age'/>
    Sex: <select name='sex'><option value='f'>Female</option><option value='m'>Male</option></select>
</form>
```

That's the basics in a nutshell.  Now for the caveats:  The above code has some type-checking in place to ensure the data being inserted into your SQL statement isn't malicious but I'd strongly advise reading up on SQL-injection attacks and making any further changes necessary to ensure security.

EDIT:  Added in type-checking to guard against SQL-injection.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi TheOX, thank you for your help, I will try it out and let you know if it works. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS (as described [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows)) which is a nice and tidy method of pagination.

So you could do the following:

```
<?php
// make sure you sanitize your inputs!
$age = $_GET['age'];
$sex = $_GET['sex'];

$rows = 10; // change to whatever number of rows you need.
$page = empty( $_GET['page'] ) ? 1 : $_GET['page'];
$page = $page < 1 ? 1 : $page;
$page = (--$page) * $rows;


$qry = "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM students
        WHERE age = :age
        AND sex = :sex
        LIMIT :page, :rows;";
$db = new PDO('mysql:dbname=yourdb:host=localhost', $username, $password);
$srch = $db->prepare($qry);
$srch->bindValue( ':age' , $age, PDO::PARAM_INT );
$srch->bindValue( ':sex' , $sex, PDO::PARAM_STR );
$srch->bindValue( ':page' , $page, PDO::PARAM_INT );
$srch->bindValue( ':page' , $rows, PDO::PARAM_INT );
$srch->execute();
$results = $srch->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );
$number = $db->query('SELECT FOUND_ROWS() AS `pages`;');
$pageNum = $number->fetch( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );

// start building your pagination.
$url = '?age='.$age.'&amp;sex='.$sex.'&amp;page=';

for( $i = 1 ; $i <= $pageNum['pages'] ; $i++ )
{
    if( $i == $page )
    {
        echo '<span>'.$i.'</span> &gt;';
    }
    else
    {
        echo '<a href="'.$url.$i.'">'.$i.'</a> &gt;';
    }
}

// your form code.
// you result listing.
```

Comment: Wow Ian, this looks like a great code, will try it out. I'm not sure I can get it to work because this is my fist time working with PDO. How do I supply the form code as commented at the bottom of your code?

Comment: form code I simply meant start outputting html. the result listing you will loop over the $results array to display your search results.